# Get certain element from webpage as embed code

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, embed

I would like to know if it's possible to rip the Meta Slider element from a WordPress post as an embed code to place on a different HTML file of different host?

[Particular Page](http://en.o2jam.v3-games.com/patch-slide/)

The link above will be the exact source and the meta slider element there is the one I would like to have the embed code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a WP wrapper for the FlexSlider jQuery plugin. Get it here: http://flexslider.woothemes.com/

Comment: but this is actually a Meta Slider plugin. reason why I just want to rip the element from there than creating different set of code on a different file is because of the workload of updating the slider.

Comment: I don't quite understand what element you want to "rip". If you need a slider on your own page that is not on WP, just include jQuery and FlexSLider, then just set up the slider and you're done. If your problem is that you don't know how to set the slider up, then check the DEMOs by the link I posted or just check the sources of the page you like.

Comment: is it possible to rip the slider from the webpage by not duplicating the plugin on a stand alone different page like what you suggested me?

Comment: If you don't want to store the scripts on your server, fine, just use them from CDN ( e.g. http://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery and http://cdnjs.com/libraries/flexslider ) by including them like so (for jquery): ```<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>```. Note that the slider setup should be done on your side anyway (either embedded on the page or in a separate script).